# MySQL : EF5.X : ASP.Net - Mapping Error

Tags: mysql, asp.net, entity-framework

I was first receiving a Primary key issue due to a MySQL server bug in the newest release that I researched on how to fix.

```
set global optimizer_switch='derived_merge=OFF';
```

Once I did this, I updated my Data Module to include some new tables that I wanted to work with. The **new** added ones work fine, however, the **two** tables prior to the update I did when adding the new **5** tables seem to show this error:

> Error: 110007: Entity type 'tbl_name' is not mapped.

This error is showing for both of the two tables I had prior to updating and adding the other **5**.

I have tried sourcing [information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931521/error-3004-mapping-error-with-ef)  from other posts but these are outdated or different error codes and seemed to have not worked when I followed the fixes suggested.

Any ideas what I can try? Thanks.

Making it a bit easier to understand, I started with 2 tables which worked fine and I have written code for. I updated the Module to add another 5 tables which I wanted to work with and they all work fine however, its the two I started with that seem to error.

EDIT: I have tried refreshing the tables already and deleting them and re-adding them and also restarting the Visual Studio.

**I found the fix [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859196/entity-framework-error-11007-entity-type-is-not-mapped)  - Vote to close.**

Comment: Please show the relevant .NET code.

Comment: There is no code in this, Entity is a Framework which you use an Entity Data Module to import your Databases into. Code is irrelevant @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: Sorry, I assumed your question was analogous to using JPA with Java.  I stand corrected (I'm not a .NET person).

Comment: I appreciate your time though, thank-you @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework - Error 11007: Entity type is not mapped.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859196/entity-framework-error-11007-entity-type-is-not-mapped)